# Large Users Profile - Windows 7 - Machine running slowly

Tags: windows-7, windows, user-profiles

I have the MD of a client of ours who has a Windows 7 Profile that is currently 14GB thanks to Videos/Music and Documents.  The first thing we did was to switch from roaming to local.  What I need to know is now the profile is local am I wasting my time by reducing it any further?  Does it really make a difference to performance having a large local user profile?

Only the 4GB outlook ost that talks to the network frequently.

Thanks in advance....

Richard

Answer (score 1):

Having a large local user profile should not impact the performance.

But if it's roaming profile that need to downloaded every time the user logs in, it will impact the performance.

User profile are store on the hard disk, whether it's in My Documents or C:\ it's on the same drive.